# How to resolve array entities in a GraphQL-Query?

Tags: typescript, api, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I have a graphql Query in which i am trying to get All the fields of Post.

```
{
    getSpaceByName(spaceName: "Anime") {
        spaceId
        spaceName
        spaceAvatarUrl
        spaceDescription
        followingIds {
            User {
                id
                name
                username
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this query there is a followingIds Array which is an Array of strings which contain all the Ids of users who follow this page.
Then i use a Field Resolver to resolver all these ids and resturn an array of users

```
  @FieldResolver(() => User)
  async followingIds(@Root() space: Spaces) {
    const spaceAcc = (await Spaces.findOne({
      where: {
        spaceName: space.spaceName,
      },
    })) as Spaces;
   const users  = []
   await users.push(await User.findByIds(spaceAcc.followingIds as string[]) as User[])
   console.log(users)
   return users
  }
```

This is what i am getting from my server
[image: this is the result]

And this is the error i get when i use to call this in my GraphQL Query.
[image]

How to resolve this User instance i am getting into all the user fields and return it withing my Graphql-Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your field resolver like this:

```js
@FieldResolver(() => [User])
async followingIds(@Root() space: Spaces) {
  const spaceAcc = (await Spaces.findOne({
    where: {
      spaceName: space.spaceName,
    },
  })) as Spaces;
  const users  = await User.findByIds(spaceAcc.followingIds as string[]) as User[];
  console.log(users);
  return users;
}
```

Then change your query like below:

```js
{
    getSpaceByName(spaceName: "Anime") {
        spaceId
        spaceName
        spaceAvatarUrl
        spaceDescription
        followingIds {
            id
            name
            username
        }
    }
}
```